# Reload sections is not calling viewForHeaderInSection

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am trying to collapse a section once selected, but my header disappears, I have tried to register the viewForHeaderInSection class in ViewDidLoad but with no success, here are the steps :

creating a button and a target action on each headers
if tapped, the collapseExpand function sets the number of rows in section to 0, then calls reloadsections at the correct index (sender button tag).

Unfortunately, once reloaded, viewForHeaderInSection is not called, and the header disappears.

any help ?

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    // reistering headerfooterview class
    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewHeaderFooterView.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "header")

}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if hookMode {
        //   print (data.count)
        return data.count
    } else {
        return 1
    }

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


    if section == selectedSection {
         return 0
    } else {

        return data[section].count

    }

}

func expandCollapse(sender: UIButton) {

    self.selectedSection = sender.tag

    tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet( index: sender.tag ), withRowAnimation: .Bottom) 

}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let header: CustomHeaderTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("header") as! CustomHeaderTableViewCell
    let button   = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
    button.frame = header.bounds
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    button.setTitle("Test Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MainWitness.expandCollapse), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    button.tag = section
    header.addSubview(button)

    if hookMode {
        // print( hookedUsernames[section] )
        header.sectionHeaderLabel.text = hookedUsernames[section]
    } else {
        header.sectionHeaderLabel.text = "TRENDS"
    }
    return header

}
```

Comment: what u getting in "numberOfSectionsInTableView" count ? and heightForHeaderInSection

Comment: I have the correct number, it works on this aspect

Comment: heightForHeaderInSection ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this in my project . what i did is created a prototype cell inside a tableview and add label and a button in the storyboard.

Created Tableviewcell class

```
class mainTableHeaderViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var _btnShowHide: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var _lblSectionHeaderName: UILabel!
}
```

in controller

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let header = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("mainTableHeaderViewCell")! as! mainTableHeaderViewCell
    header._lblSectionHeaderName.text = objTempDeficiencyList[section][0].sectionName
    // sectionNameList[section].DESCRIPTION
    header._btnShowHide.addTarget(self, action: "hideSection:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    if hiddenSections.contains(section) {
        header._btnShowHide.setImage(UIImage(named: "expand"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
    else {
        header._btnShowHide.setImage(UIImage(named: "uparrow"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }

    header._btnShowHide.tag = section
    return header.contentView
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 40
}

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if hiddenSections.contains(section) {
        return 0
    }
    return List[section].count // getRowCount(section)
}
```

Hope this help .